# Is grounding required for new propane cooktop with new propane tank install

Tags: grounding, propane

I want to replace an electric cooktop with a propane gas one.  The cooktop will be placed next to an exterior wall and the propane tanks will be just on the other side of the wall.  So, it will be a very short run using black pipe and the propane will not be used only for the cooktop.  The cooktop requires electric for the ignitors and will be plugged into a GFI outlet.   My question does this setup require grounding of the propane tank or gas line and if so does it have to be grounded at the service panel? Or is there another means of grounding I can to as the service panel is more than 75 feet away?

Comment: What does the manual/installation guide say?

Comment: Low level tip: Why don't you use a lighter for ignition?

Comment: Chris - the installation manual doesn't really address the gas line only to not cut the grounding prong from the plug and to use a grounded outlet (which is standard for most electrical devices).

Comment: Rubus - that was an option we were thinking about as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The gas pipe is grounded by the appliance, and that's apparently it, modulo local codes

Under current national codes (NFPA 58 for propane, IFGC or NFGC/NFPA 54 for the gas piping), the gas line is grounded by way of the grounding wire in the cooktop due to it being black iron (instead of CSST, which needs a bit of help with the "conducting electricity" thing in most cases).

As to the propane tank itself? Best I can tell from NFPA 58 (6.25.1.x), there are no grounding or bonding requirements for propane tanks themselves. Your local AHJ may have other ideas, though, so I'd check with them, or at the very least your propane supplier, to make sure that there are no local requirements for grounding and bonding of the tank.